# Appending random query string value to image URL is not refreshing it

Tags: html, caching, iis-7, webserver

We have a web-based CCTV system - each camera effectively acts like a web server, and you simply browse to a URL to see the camera's image.

I've written a simple HTML page that "aggregates" each camera's image onto a single page. I use javascript to append a random query string value onto each image URL every couple of seconds, forcing the images to refresh. A URL might look something like this:

`http://192.168.50.100/camera1/current.jpg?rand=324923`

When this HTML page is viewed from the internal network, it all works fine.

Now, I've also created an "external" version of the page on our DMZ, so managers can view the CCTV while off-site. The HTML is identical to the "internal" page except for the image URLs, which are something like this:-

`http://foo.com:1234/camera1/current.jpg?rand=...`

Each camera has a different port number, so I'm assuming the IT guys are using some kind of port-forwarding. When you view this page, the camera images do appear initially, but don't refresh. In some cases it shows images that were captured seconds or even minutes ago. Using Chrome's F12 feature, I can see the random number changing in the image URLs, so I know the javascript is working.

Any idea why this external page isn't refreshing? It seems that something is serving up cached images, and ignoring the changing query string (the whole point of which should be to request an uncached version).

Comment: To the client, a different URL means a whole different resource, so he has no choice but to request it from the server. So the caching issue can only be with your cameras themselves – “new” image gets requested, but no new image data available – so they send out the same image data as for the last request.

Comment: The CCTV system captures at 15 fps so there are always new images. I can view both versions of my HTML page side by side - the "internal" page on an office PC and the "external" page via wifi. The "internal" page refreshes but not the "external" page, suggesting something along the network route taken by the external page is caching.

Comment: OK, it might not be the cameras themselves, but something in between in your DMZ. But if this is the case, then some of the components is violating HTTP with its caching behavior – as I said, appending a different query string makes it a whole different resource, so no client is allowed to take it from any cache, because he __can not__ have it cached for the simple reason that it is a different, “new” URL. Are there any log files available for your DMZ machines, where you can see how the requests are handled?